# Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

Below is the code, in which I'm getting stuck. It is throwing an exception and I'm unable to solve it.

```
import 'package:attendance_worklog/Events/eventSchedule.dart';
import 'package:attendance_worklog/login/loginModel.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'eventScheduleModel.dart';

class EventScheduleService extends EventSchedule{
  LoginModel? data;
  EventScheduleService({required this.data}) : super(data: data);
  var url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5001/naf-vip-server/us-central1/api/meets/');
  Future<List<EventScheduleModel>?> getSchedule() async{
    try{
      print("In Try");
      final response = await http.get(url,headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ${data!.token}'});
      if (response.statusCode == 200){
        print("In If");
        final List<EventScheduleModel> eventScheduleModel = eventScheduleModelFromJson(response.body) as List<EventScheduleModel>;
        print(eventScheduleModel);
        return eventScheduleModel;
      }else{
        print("0");
        return <EventScheduleModel>[];
      }
    }catch (e){
      print("0 excep");
      print(e);
      return <EventScheduleModel>[];
    }
  }
}
```

when called function following is the output:

```
I/flutter (18763): In Try
I/flutter (18763): In If
I/flutter (18763): 0 excep
I/flutter (18763): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

that means `final List<EventScheduleModel> eventScheduleModel = eventScheduleModelFromJson(response.body) as List<EventScheduleModel>;` is having some issue.

Throwing exception as `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

Please help if someone knows the solution.

Comment: Hi Ayan, can you show us what the response.body looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` on `response.body` because `response.body` is `List` of `Map<String, dynamic>`.

```dart
final List<EventScheduleModel> eventScheduleModel = (response.body as List)
    .map((e) => eventScheduleModelFromJson(e))
    .toList();
```